# Scylla JMX - How is the MBean org.apache.cassandra.metrics:keyspace=uzzstore,name=EstimatedRowCount,scope=chunks,type=ColumnFamily mapped in the API?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

Scylla exposes JMX mbeans via its internal API (or the maybe the other way around, but it does not matter). For example I can access the MBean `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:name=LiveDiskSpaceUsed,type=ColumnFamily` invoking `http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/live_disk_space_used`.

How can I read the MBean

```
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:keyspace=uzzstore,name=EstimatedRowCount,scope=chunks,type=ColumnFamily
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/estimated_row_count`.

You can find these metrics by looking at which metrics the scylla-jmx tool uses, or looking at ScyllaDB source code; But you can also conveniently explore the metrics exported by a running ScyllaDB with the UI: `http://localhost:10000/ui/`. Open this URL in a browser, and it shows you the full list of REST API requests. If you dive into `/column_family/` you can see the full list of metrics, a (very short...) description of each, and even the ability to try them out on-the-fly.

UPDATE:

This is a per-table metric, so you need to specify the table name at the end of the path. Specify it as keyspace name, colon, and a table name. So try something like `http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/estimated_row_count/yourkeyspacename:yourtablename`.

Comment: It looks like it is not there... 

wget http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/estimated_row_count
--2023-10-25 13:33:36--  http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/estimated_row_count
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:10000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-10-25 13:33:36 ERROR 404: Not Found.
Also, how to get the metrics for a given table (like the MBean above)?

Comment: As the name "column_family" in the path suggests, this is a per-column-family (i.e., per-table) estimate. The table name is specified as keyspace name, colon, and a table name. So try something like `http://localhost:10000/column_family/metrics/estimated_row_count/yourkeyspacename:yourtablename`.